# Magento category next page gone

Tags: magento-1.9

I lost a part of code in my category page. I dont have the switch at the bottom for the second page or the 3rd page. When i set the product total towards 9 there doesn't come a button to switch to page 2 on the bottom. This is my code for the category page 2columns-left.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after_body_start') ?>
<div class="wrapper">
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices') ?>
<div class="page">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>

    <div class="main-container col-layouts col2-layout col2-left-layout">
        <div class="content-container">
            <div class="main row">
                <div class="col-main-wrap">
                    <div class="col-main grid_13">
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="sidebar col-left grid_5">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left'); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>
    </div>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_cookie_notice') ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end') ?>
</div>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getAbsoluteFooter() ?>
```

What can be the problem? What code am i missing?

Comment: how you realised that you "lost" a chunk of code?

Comment: I have been searching for the problem, but I cant find another reason why it is gone. Any ide?

Comment: do you have the original files from your template? if yes just copy and paste the file that you need(if of course you did not make any changes on that file) and see what happens.

Comment: @Vsld no i don't have any file where it is found in. I think i am missing some lines of code.